# Run-time error '1004' Select method of Worksheet class failed, on worksheet opening

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to be having an issue with my workbook. It comes up with the Run-time error '1004'  Select method of Worksheet class failed when I copy it into a new folder or rename it. The code is simple. I am new to VBA and don't know how to set workbook or sheets as Active correctly.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("QUOTE SETUP").Visible = True
Sheets("QUOTE SETUP").Select
Range("F6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It's completely unlikely, that renaming the file or moving it to different location would trigger such issue. Your code works for me just fine, when I hide "QUOTE SETUP" worksheet, save file and then open it.

Comment: That you i think know a bit more now as to why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Thank you for that. I think I know a bit more now as to why I'm getting this error. The workbook is password protected and read-only set on it. After renaming the file in the folder, then when you open it for the first time after that. You have to enable editing, then enter the password. After that a second workbook open with the same name. book 01 is [Protected View] and book 02 normal. That's when I get the error. Could it be that it's looking at both books due to them having the same name?

Comment: I think I fixed it but I don't understand how or why it's fixed.     
    <pre>
'Fix below
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Wsh As Object)

On Error Resume Next
Wsh.Range("F6").Select
End Sub <code>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that. I think I know a bit more now as to why I'm getting this error. The workbook is password protected and read-only set on it. After renaming the file in the folder, then when you open it for the first time after that. You have to enable editing, then enter the password. After that a second workbook open with the same name. book 01 is [Protected View] and book 02 normal. That's when I get the error. Could it be that it's looking at both books due to them having the same name?

I think I fixed it by copying something I found online but I don't understand it really how or why it's now fixed but it works. 
I am new to VBA and code, thank you for your time I appreciate all the help and feedback.

```
'Fix below 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Wsh As Object) 
On Error Resume Next 
Wsh.Range("F6").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: This "fix" is a line `On Error Resume Next ` to ignore any errors in code below it. If any happens, code will execute till the end, BUT obviously if there is error on `Wsh.Range("F6").Select `, F6 will not be selected.

Comment: Thank so not a fix a skip lol it may just have to do for now.